# Convert string to XML format in C language

Tags: c, xml, string, converters

I have a question, is there an algorithm that converts the corresponding logical expression as a string to xml format?

For example:

I am loading logical expressions as a string from the input file:

`(X&Y)|Z`

And now to convert it into xml format, to get something like this in a new file:

```
 <expression>
     <or>
        <operand>Z</operand>
             <and>
                 <operand>X</operand>
                 <operand>Y</operand>
             </and>
     </or>
</expression>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need a parser for your expression language and you'd then serialize the parsed tree into XML.

Answer (score 0):

(Responding to the [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) tag.)

Perhaps you can make use of [invisible-xml](/questions/tagged/invisible-xml) (ixml),
the SO [Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/invisible-xml/info)
tab lists several resources.

With a grammar such as

```
ixml version "1.0".

expression: expr.
-expr: operand; and; or; not.
and: expr, -"&", expr.
or: expr, -"|", expr.
not: -"!", operand.
-operand: id; -"(", expr, -")".
id: letter.
-letter: ["A"-"Z"].
```

the `ixml` processor [`coffeepot`](https://coffeepot.nineml.org/)

```sh
java -jar '/usr/local/share/java/coffeepot-1.99.11.jar' \
  --grammar:expr-bool.ixml --pretty-print '(X&Y)|Z'
```

produces the following output:

```xml
<expression>
   <or>
      <and>
         <id>X</id>
         <id>Y</id>
      </and>
      <id>Z</id>
   </or>
</expression>
```

---

With the input `(X&Y)|Z&!(A|B)` `coffeepot` (by default) outputs the
first of (in this case 2) possible parses and emits the root element as
`<expression xmlns:ixml="http://invisiblexml.org/NS" ixml:state="ambiguous">`
to point out the ambiguity.

If parsing fails the output could be something like:

```xml
<fail xmlns:ixml="http://invisiblexml.org/NS" ixml:state="failed">
   <line>1</line>
   <column>14</column>
   <pos>14</pos>
   <end-of-input>true</end-of-input>
   <permitted>['A'-'Z']</permitted>
</fail>
```